# Elasticsearch query to get the range between 0 to 5 & 6 to 10 records

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run the below query facing the following error:

```json
{
  "type": "parsing_exception",
  "reason": "Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [field]."
}
```

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": { "answer.keyword": "NOTANSWERED" }
  },
  "fields": ["question.keyword", "answer.keyword"],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error caused by there's no `fields` key `Elasticsearch` query, it's `_source`, for instance:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": { "answer.keyword": "NOTANSWERED" }
  },
  "_source": ["question", "answer"],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5
}
```

Also, you don't have to add `.keyword` suffix for `_source` key.

Comment: Which Elasticsearch version do you use?

Comment: "Version number" : "7.4.0",

Comment: When we execute your correct query. I am getting this response .** {
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
 **

Comment: Not getting the fields as expected

Comment: I'm using Elasticsearch 6.4 and that how I get fields, but you got response instead of error, which means _source is working

Comment: Also, you got a response with an empty hits array, which means there's no issue with the fields, it's now all about `from` and `size`, try to get them all to check the result

Comment: Yes source working but I want the output **List of Questions & Answers**. How to get the list. I guess this query wont solve my purpose

Comment: My friend; you got an empty `hits` array with `total:1` hits, try to remove `from` and `size` to check the issue source.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas it was added in version 7, not before.

Comment: I tried removing from and size but still getting same previous response.. my Requirement is I want to display the data with the question & answer  & we’re looking for documents 0 to 10 (starting at 1 and counting 10 documents).